# Calendar Navigation button events

Tags: fullcalendar

Anyone know how to test for fullcalendar  navigation button events. I need to know when a user presses the Previous or Next Month buttons. I do not find this event address in the documentation, but if may be called something different then I am looking for.

I have a large calendar that has a year of history and I am trying to only load the current month of events to reduce load time. The historical events are used for tracking events.

I would appreciate an help.....

Answer (score 1):

See callback function [viewDisplay](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewDisplay/) ...